# async/await IIFE

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await

Would anyone be so kind to assist me if I’m ‘cooking’ async/await a right way?

I attend to return an express response once promise to DB resolves.

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  (async function() {
    try {
      const cases = await db.collections.cases.stats();

      return res.render('index', {
        title: 'Welcome',
        totalDBRecords: cases.count,
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      next(e);
    }
  })();
});
```

Comment: The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://CodeReview.meta.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to wrap this in an IFFE. You can simply write the async function as follows:

```js
router.get('/', async (res, req, next) => {
     try {
         const cases = await db.collections.cases.stats();

         res.render('index', {
             title: 'Welcome',
             totalDBRecords: cases.count,
         });
     } catch(err) {
          console.log(err);
          next(err);
     }
});
```

That should work. I also like the way [Wes Bos](https://twitter.com/wesbos) wraps his functions in an error handler, like so (eliminates having to use try/catch).

```
const catchErr = (fn) => {
    return function(res, req, next) {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
    }
};    
const home = async (res, req, next) => {
     const cases = await db.collections.cases.stats();
     res.render('index', {
         title: 'Welcome',
         totalDBRecords: cases.count,
     });
};
router.get('/', catchErr(home));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
I really like the 'Wes Bos' version, especially its readability.

Comment: He has a great course on learning Node, if you're interested: https://learnnode.com